# How to know width = ? px = % in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML / CSS, I am currently doing code to practice with my lesson, but I am wondering about that one issue about px and % when setting the width of the web page.
I want to know that:  **`width = 1px =?%;`**
can anyone help me, I already searched but there does not have any answer, thank you so much

Comment: `%` is calculated based on the width of the parent DOM, and `px` is a fixed value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The percentage is always calculated in relation to the containing block. So if for example the containing block is `100px` and you want the width of your contained div to be `1px` but want to express it in terms of percentage, then you would have to right it as `1%`.

TL;DR: for a containing block of 100px `width: 1px` = `width: 1%`.